# Android: How do I loop sound effects?

Tags: java, android, audio, soundpool

I have two sound effects assigned to a button. I'm wondering how I can loop back to the first sound effect, after the last one is played.

```
mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.finn_whatthejugisthat);
mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.jake_dancingwithbabes);
mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.lsp_dontlumpingyellatme);
mSoundManager.addSound(4, R.raw.pb_shouldntpunchbrainiacs);
mSoundManager.addSound(5, R.raw.iceking_imabanana);
mSoundManager.addSound(5, R.raw.finn_wordtoyourmother);

final Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(1, 0);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(6, 0);


    }

});
    }
});
```

**SoundManger.java**

```
package com.andrew.finnandjake;

import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;

public class SoundManager {

static private SoundManager _instance;
private static SoundPool mSoundPool;
private static HashMap mSoundPoolMap;
private static AudioManager mAudioManager;
private static Context mContext;

SoundManager() {
}

/**
 * Requests the instance of the Sound Manager and creates it if it does not
 * exist.
 * 
 * @return Returns the single instance of the SoundManager
 */
static synchronized public SoundManager getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null)
        _instance = new SoundManager();
    return _instance;
}

/**
 * Initialises the storage for the sounds
 * 
 * @param theContext
 *            The Application context
 */
public static void initSounds(Context theContext) {
    mContext = theContext;
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap();
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
}

/**
 * Add a new Sound to the SoundPool
 * 
 * @param Index
 *            - The Sound Index for Retrieval
 * @param SoundID
 *            - The Android ID for the Sound asset.
 */
public static void addSound(int Index, int SoundID) {
    mSoundPoolMap.put(Index, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));
}

/**
 * Loads the various sound assets Currently hardcoded but could easily be
 * changed to be flexible.
 */
public static void loadSounds() {
    mSoundPoolMap.put(1, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.finn_whatthejugisthat, 1));
    mSoundPoolMap.put(2, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.jake_dancingwithbabes, 1));
    mSoundPoolMap.put(3, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.lsp_dontlumpingyellatme, 1));
    mSoundPoolMap.put(4, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.pb_shouldntpunchbrainiacs, 1));
    mSoundPoolMap.put(5, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.iceking_imabanana, 1));
}


/**
 * Plays a Sound
 * 
 * @param index
 *            - The Index of the Sound to be played
 * @param speed
 *            - The Speed to play not, not currently used but included for
 *            compatibility
 */
public static void playSound(int index, float speed) {
    float streamVolume = mAudioManager
            .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    streamVolume = streamVolume
            / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mSoundPool.play((Integer) mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume,
            1, 0, speed);
}

/**
 * Stop a Sound
 * 
 * @param index
 *            - index of the sound to be stopped
 */
public static void stopSound(int index) {
    mSoundPool.stop((Integer) mSoundPoolMap.get(index));
}

/**
 * Deallocates the resources and Instance of SoundManager
 */
public static void cleanup() {
    mSoundPool.release();
    mSoundPool = null;
    mSoundPoolMap.clear();
    mAudioManager.unloadSoundEffects();
    _instance = null;

}

public int getNumberOfSounds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehhmm...

```
final Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    int currentSound = 0;
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(currentSound, 0);
        currentSound++;
        currentSound %= mSoundmanager.getNumberOfSounds();
    }
});
```

If I understand your code right, you want to play a different sound each time the button is pressed.

Comment: @EboMike Right, each button press is a different sound effect. I don't understand your answer.

Comment: Okay, what's there not to understand?

Comment: @EboMike How do I apply specific sounds to button 1? Am I suppose to replace "current sound" with the one I want? Ultimately, I'm going to end up with 5 buttons and about 7 sound effects for each one.

Comment: What is it that you want? Your example makes it look like you want to cycle through a list of sounds each time the button is pressed, which is what this code does. `currentSound` is the sound that will be played the first time the button is pressed.

Comment: @EboMike I just can't see how that code tells the button which sound effects to cycle through. Should I make a separate class for each button I have? 

The sound effects I have above are not all for button 1, only 1 and 6 are.

Comment: I have no idea what your code is like. You don't show what `SoundManager` is. You don't show what exactly you want to do with each button press. I showed you the idea (you maintain the index and move it with each press), you need to adapt it to your code. Without more information, that's all I can give you.